# View is blank after modalViewController is dismissed

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am using [PPRevealSideViewController](https://github.com/ipup/PPRevealSideViewController/) and I am showing a ViewController modally after user taps a cell in a side view. When I dismiss a modal view controller, the view, where user tapped, is shown blank. Only after I move a little bit side view, it is shown again (refreshed). What might be the problem?
[image: screen shot iOS simulator]

Comment: This should't happen. Try reviewing the documentation, I think you are missing something. The sdk should be ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a side effect of your preload call on viewWillAppear or DidAppear in fact. The view should not be preloaded if shown. I added this behavior as default into the controller.
But the idea behind was to test if [self.revealSideController sideDirectionOpened] != PPRevealSideDirection from the side you are trying to preload.

Fixed right here https://github.com/ipup/PPRevealSideViewController/commit/a1ca242422f0a8b4666df5987ca4a020f869bb99